# read json object on cordova android

Tags: android, json, cordova

i have a json object like this, name response.friends.data:

```
[
   id: "xxxxxxxxxx"
   name: "xxxxxxxxxx"
   picture: Object
      data: Object
         is_silhouette: false
         url: "https://17021429_1106487322811185_5736978578202826559_n.jpg?oh…"
]
```

I read it like this:

```
for (key in response.friends.data) {
    fb_friends.push([response.friends.data[key]['id'], response.friends.data[key]['name'], response.friends.data[key]['picture'].data['url'], '']);                     
}
```

it works on android api 25 Nougat but it doesn't work on adroid api 21 Lollipop, and it works on ios.
On android 21 i have this error:

Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined in

if i don't put response.friends.data[key]['picture'].data['url'] it works so i think error is on .data['url']

if someone have an idea i have try to read this json with different way, but i always have this error.
Tell me if you need more explications.

Sorry for my english, Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I think the simplest way to use JSONObjects is to use [org.json](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html). And it'll work on any of these devices.

Comment: yes but i use javascript so i don't think i can use this?